# how do I place custom error messages at the top of a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, message

Such a novice question, but I can't seem to resolve this.

if I have a simple Rails 2.3.5 form :

```
- form_for CardSignup.new do |f|
   = f.error_messages
  .grid_1.alpha.align_right
    = f.label :zip_code, 'zip'
  .grid_1.omega.alpha
    = f.text_field :zip_code, :style => "width: 75px;"
    %div{:class => 'error_message'}
  .clear
```

How do I make the `error_message` appear at the top of the form, rather than in the particular place of the form?

I was using this : `= f.error_messages` , but it doesn't show any content when put at the top of the form.

Comment: Where does the error message appear at the moment?

Comment: Where the div class 'error_message' is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `CardSignup.new` in the view rather than defining `@card_signup = CardSignup.new` in the controller? If you are doing like that you can call

```
<%= @card_signup.error_messages %>
```

or

```
<%= error_messages_for :card_signup %>
```

anywhere in the view file and it will show the error messages for `@card_signup` object and you can call your form like this:

```
<% form_for @card_signup do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

hah I was looking for this too. Anyways this is how I figured it out.
So all we need to do is update flash[:alert] or whatever and have that flash[:alert] at the top of your layout file.
Now 
all u do if

```
<%= simple_form_for(@boing) do |f| %>
  <% if @boing.errors.any? %>
    <% flash[:alert] = "stuff" %>
  <% end %>
....
```

now you don't want `<%= flash[:alert] = "stuff" %>` otherwise it will display at both places-inline and at top as <%= %> is for displaying in browser.
Hope that helps